# Connection Issue with Rstan/Rcpp with file29e283457dac.cpp

Tags: r, rcpp, stan, rstan

I'm trying to get a Stan modeling working in R/RStudio.

I used the code at this link (example 1): https://rdrr.io/cran/rstan/man/stan.html

```
library(rstan)
scode <- "
parameters {
real y[2]; 
} 
model {
y[1] ~ normal(0, 1);
y[2] ~ double_exponential(0, 2);
} 
"
fit1 <- stan(model_code = scode, iter = 10, verbose = FALSE) 
print(fit1)
fit2 <- stan(fit = fit1, iter = 10000, verbose = FALSE) 

## using as.array on the stanfit object to get samples 
a2 <- as.array(fit2)

## extract samples as a list of arrays
e2 <- extract(fit2, permuted = FALSE)
```

I get the following error:

Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In system(cmd, intern = !verbose) :
running command 'C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-40~1.2/bin/x64/R CMD SHLIB file29e283457dac.cpp 2> file29e283457dac.cpp.err.txt' had status 1
2: In file(con, "r") :
cannot open file 'file29e283457dac.cpp.err.txt': No such file or directory
Error in sink(type = "output") : invalid connection

Rstan devtools info

```
devtools::session_info("rstan")
- Session info ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 setting  value                       
 version  R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)
 os       Windows >= 8 x64            
 system   x86_64, mingw32             
 ui       RStudio                     
 language (EN)                        
 collate  English_United States.1252  
 ctype    English_United States.1252  
 tz       America/Los_Angeles         
 date     2020-07-06                  

- Packages -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 ! package      * version   date       lib source        
   assertthat     0.2.1     2019-03-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
   backports      1.1.7     2020-05-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
   BH             1.72.0-3  2020-01-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
   callr          3.4.3     2020-03-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
   checkmate      2.0.0     2020-02-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
   cli            2.0.2     2020-02-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
   colorspace     1.4-1     2019-03-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
   crayon         1.3.4     2017-09-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
   desc           1.2.0     2018-05-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
   digest         0.6.25    2020-02-23 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
   ellipsis       0.3.1     2020-05-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
   evaluate       0.14      2019-05-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
   fansi          0.4.1     2020-01-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
   farver         2.0.3     2020-01-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
   ggplot2        3.3.2     2020-06-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
   glue           1.4.1     2020-05-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
   gridExtra      2.3       2017-09-09 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
   gtable         0.3.0     2019-03-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
   inline         0.3.15    2018-05-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
   isoband        0.2.2     2020-06-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
   labeling       0.3       2014-08-23 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
   lattice        0.20-41   2020-04-02 [2] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
   lifecycle      0.2.0     2020-03-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
   loo            2.2.0     2019-12-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
   magrittr       1.5       2014-11-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
   MASS           7.3-51.6  2020-04-26 [2] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
   Matrix         1.2-18    2019-11-27 [2] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
   matrixStats    0.56.0    2020-03-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
   mgcv           1.8-31    2019-11-09 [2] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
   munsell        0.5.0     2018-06-12 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
   nlme           3.1-148   2020-05-24 [2] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
   pillar         1.4.4     2020-05-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
   pkgbuild       1.0.8     2020-05-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
   pkgconfig      2.0.3     2019-09-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
   pkgload        1.1.0     2020-05-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
   praise         1.0.0     2015-08-11 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
   prettyunits    1.1.1     2020-01-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
   processx       3.4.3     2020-07-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
   ps             1.3.3     2020-05-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
   R6             2.4.1     2019-11-12 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
   RColorBrewer   1.1-2     2014-12-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
   Rcpp           1.0.5     2020-07-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
   RcppEigen      0.3.3.7.0 2019-11-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 D RcppParallel   5.0.2     2020-06-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
   rlang          0.4.6     2020-05-02 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
   rprojroot      1.3-2     2018-01-03 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
   rstan          2.19.3    2020-02-11 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
   rstudioapi     0.11      2020-02-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
   scales         1.1.1     2020-05-11 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
   StanHeaders    2.21.0-5  2020-06-09 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
   testthat       2.3.2     2020-03-02 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
   tibble         3.0.1     2020-04-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
   utf8           1.1.4     2018-05-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
   vctrs          0.3.1     2020-06-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
   viridisLite    0.3.0     2018-02-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
   withr          2.2.0     2020-04-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)

[1] C:/Users/Wesley Engers/Documents/R/win-library/4.0
[2] C:/Program Files/R/R-4.0.2/library

 D -- DLL MD5 mismatch, broken installation.
```

I'm running a Windows machine with R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22). I tried uninstalling and reinstalling RcppParallel but didn't seem to help. Let me know if you need any additional
info. Any help as to how to fix this error would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: Addressing Ben's comment. There was a bunch of code before this but I believe this is the error part. Output with verbose=TRUE from `stan` function.

```
Compilation argument:
 C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-40~1.2/bin/x64/R CMD SHLIB file68206e4a2c56.cpp 2> file68206e4a2c56.cpp.err.txt 
"C:/rtools40/mingw64/bin/"g++  -std=gnu++14 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-40~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG   -I"C:/Users/Wesley Engers/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/Rcpp/include/"  -I"C:/Users/Wesley Engers/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/RcppEigen/include/"  -I"C:/Users/Wesley Engers/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/RcppEigen/include/unsupported"  -I"C:/Users/Wesley Engers/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/BH/include" -I"C:/Users/Wesley Engers/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/StanHeaders/include/src/"  -I"C:/Users/Wesley Engers/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/StanHeaders/include/"  -I"C:/Users/Wesley Engers/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/rstan/include" -DEIGEN_NO_DEBUG  -D_REENTRANT  -DBOOST_DISABLE_ASSERTS -DBOOST_PENDING_INTEGER_LOG2_HPP -include stan/math/prim/mat/fun/Eigen.hpp  -std=c++1y    -march=corei7 -mtune=corei7   -include C:/Users/Wesley Engers/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/StanHeaders/include/stan/math/prim/mat/fun/Eigen.hpp -I "C:/Users/Wesley Engers/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/StanHeaders/include" -I "C:/Users/Wesley E... <truncated>
g++.exe: error: Engers/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/StanHeaders/include/stan/math/prim/mat/fun/Eigen.hpp: No such file or directory
make: *** [C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-40~1.2/etc/x64/Makeconf:229: file68206e4a2c56.o] Error 1
Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection
```

Update 2: This is the error I get now after installing the StanHeaders suggested by Ben.

```
Error in compileCode(f, code, language = language, verbose = verbose) : 
  Compilation ERROR, function(s)/method(s) not created! C:/rtools40/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: filece9460ea6ca8.o:filece9460ea6ca8.cpp:(.text+0x9d7): undefined reference to `rstan::stan_fit::stan_fit(SEXPREC*, int)'
C:/rtools40/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: filece9460ea6ca8.o:filece9460ea6ca8.cpp:(.text+0xabc): undefined reference to `tbb::internal::task_scheduler_observer_v3::observe(bool)'
C:/rtools40/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: filece9460ea6ca8.o:filece9460ea6ca8.cpp:(.text+0xafe): undefined reference to `tbb::internal::task_scheduler_observer_v3::observe(bool)'
C:/rtools40/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: filece9460ea6ca8.o:filece9460ea6ca8.cpp:(.text$_ZN3tbb8internal26task_scheduler_observer_v3D1Ev[_ZN3tbb8internal26task_scheduler_
```

Comment: You need to call `stan` with `verbose = TRUE` to see the actual error message.

Comment: Added an edit as I don't have enough space in a comment.

Comment: This may solve your issue: https://discourse.mc-stan.org/t/trouble-finding-eigen-hpp/14282

Comment: @duckmayr, thanks for the link. Still seem to be getting the same error though.

Comment: You are going to temporarily need https://discourse.mc-stan.org/t/stan-not-running-after-updating-to-r-version-4-0-2-and-stan-updated-from-2-19-3-to-2-21/16519/19?u=bgoodri but that won't be necessary once I can get a new StanHeaders onto CRAN.

Comment: Thanks for the link @BenGoodrich. I believe I'm getting a different error now. See updated post. Thanks for all your help so far.